# Can't get flash or error messages to display on button submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this form and I'm trying to submit the contents of the form to the model "Leeds" then display a success/failure message depending on if the data passes the model validations.

The issue I'm having is that when I click on the "Send Message" button, it takes me from `Root` to  `Root/leeds`.

This is the form I'm using:

```
<%= form_for @leed, {url:root_path, html: {id:"contactForm", name:"sentMessage", novalidate:true}} do |leed| %>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <!-- Name -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= leed.text_field :name, class: "form-control", :placeholder => "Your name *", :required => true, :data => {:validation_required_message => 'Please enter your name.' }  %>
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
                <!-- Email -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= leed.email_field :email, class: "form-control", :placeholder => "Your email *", :required => true, :data => {:validation_required_message => 'Please enter your email address.' } %>
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
                <!-- Phone -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= leed.telephone_field :phone, class: "form-control", :placeholder => "Your phone *", :required => true, :data => {:validation_required_message => 'Please enter your phone number.' } %>
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Message -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <%= leed.text_area :message, class: "form-control", :placeholder => "Your message *", :required => true, :data => {:validation_required_message => 'Please enter a message.' } %>
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <!-- Submit -->
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <div id="success">
                    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
                </div>
                <%= button_tag "Send Message", class: "btn btn-xl" %>
            </div>

    </div>
<% end %>
```

This is my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
  post "/" => 'home#create'
end
```

This is the HomeController method I have:

```
  def create
    @leed = Leed.new(leed_params)
    if @leed.save
      #update page to reflect success
      flash[:success] = "Thank you, we'll contact you as soon as possible"
    else
      #update page to flect failure
      flash[:danger] = "There was an issue with the login attempt #{@leed.errors.full_messages.inspect}"
    end
    # redirect_to thank_you.html.erb
    render nothing:true
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your #create method you have `render nothing: true`. This means the post request will be submitted to /leads, but then the server won't tell the browser to go anywhere else, so the browser will stay at the /leads url. You can add a redirect at the end of your create action if you want the browser to be redirected to a different page after the post request is completed. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, issue is, it's a single page site so there's no where else I really want it to go to. I'm trying to simply displaythe message that it was successful or it wasn't through a hidden div, but the user would remain on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Puhlze is right, you should be able to have the page redirect to itself where the Flash message should show up. You could also make the form `remote: true` and create a `create.js.erb` file that will popup a notification message without re-rendering the page; that's what we usually do when we are using AJAX submits.

Comment: I like the idea of using create.js.erb for the popup display. Right now the only option I've found working is to use `render :index` which cause the page to reload, but shows the flash. It's not terrible, but I'd much prefer accomplishing this without the reload. I'm just not sure how to implement this with Rails. Do you have an example I could follow? I have no idea how to implement JS with Rails just yet.

Comment: Hey Batman, yeah that render :index will work if you want to refresh the page. If you don't you need to use JS! Here are a couple options: [Bootstrap-Notify](http://goodybag.github.io/bootstrap-notify/) looks pretty straightforward and clean, matches Bootstrap formatting, and [Gritter](https://github.com/RobinBrouwer/gritter) looks like it has more features and is a little more complex UI wise. I'd suggest the Bootstrap one especially if you are already using it for styling